# Can't change my object duration on timeline

Tags: timeline

Total noob question, but how do I change the duration (in/out point) as to where it cuts in and out (appears) on the timeline.

Comment: You may use a Dope Sheet Editor (https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/dope_sheet.html).

Answer (score 6):

First go to the **[Timeline](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/timeline.html)** window.

There you can define your rendering and playback range by choosing your start frame and end frame:

[image]

In order to adjust your keyframes
open the **[Dope Sheet](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/dope_sheet.html)** window:

[image]

1. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all keyframes
2. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to border select the keyframes you want to adjust
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd> to move the selected keyframes to the desired position